# SQL Query to find total number of students enrolled in a subject

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Class Table has `class_id` and `class_name` columns with the ff values:

```
class_id | class_Name
1        | Algebra
2        | History
3        | PE
```

Student table has `student_id` and `student_name` column:

```
student_id | student_name
1          | Kylo Ren
2          | Rey
```

The third table which is a junction table for both table has the following columns `class_id` and `student_id`

```
class_id | student_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 1
3        | 2
```

How can I find the number of students enrolled per subjects?

Output should be like this

```
Class Name           | Number of Students
Algebra              | 2
History              | 1
PE                   | 1
```

Then after that edit the query so that it would only show the class name and number of students greater than 2

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: my bad, edited it.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I got this wrong...

```
SELECT 
    c.class_name "Class Name", 
    count(distinct j.student_id) "Number of Students"
FROM
    class c
    LEFT JOIN junction j ON j.class_id = c.class_id
GROUP BY
    1
```

Comment: Wow, this is actually correct. Can you modify the query to  only list classes with 2 students or more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate the junction table by student, and then assert that a matching student has all courses:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM junction
    GROUP BY student_id
    HAVING COUNT(class_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class)
)

SELECF COUNT(*) AS num_all_classes FROM cte;
```